# Different Number of items in flex rows with css layout

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors, vaadin

[image: jklj here]

In the mobile version of my application, I have the following items for header layout. App logo, "logged in" text, username, and logout button. What I want is

1. Logo should be on top left of the header
2. Logged in: admin should appear on the same line and right aligned
3. Under them , logout button should also be aligned to the right side.

I'm using vaadin and that allows me to write css, where I decided I could do this with flex display but I can't get it working, how could I achieve it?

My current css looks like this:

```
/* On screens that are 600px or less, set the background color to olive */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .header-layout {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .logo {
        flex: 1;
        align-self: flex-start;
    }
    .application-name {
        display: none
    }
    .admin-text {
        flex: 0 50%;
    }
    .user-name {
    flex: 0 50%;
    }
    .logout-button {
        flex: 0.5;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: provide HTML code...

Comment: there is no html, this is a java technology that allows you to embed css for the items and the items are named above inside the css

Comment: but we can't do CSS without checking the code.  have any live links or anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be using [justify-content](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/):

In the `html` wrap everything in a div called `flex` and then split the two areas in `top` and `bottom`:

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="top">
    `Here insert the logo and logged in`
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    `Here insert logout button`
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, within the `CSS`:

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```